# Eager loading does not return anything

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

When I eager load like this:

```
 return Port::filter($filters)
            ->with(['scores' => function ($query) {
                    $query->select(["*"]);
                }]
            )
            ->actives()
            ->paginate(14);
```

I get the expected result. However when I select specific column names:

```
 return Port::filter($filters)
            ->with(['scores' => function ($query) {
                    $query->select(["id, name"]);
                }]
            )
            ->actives()
            ->paginate(14);
```

Result is always `[]`. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In select we need to pass column names separated by comma's

```
 return Port::filter($filters)
        ->with(['scores' => function ($query) {
                $query->select("id", "name");
            }]
        )
        ->actives()
        ->paginate(14);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use [ ] outside column names with comma separated as below.

```
 return Port::filter($filters)
        ->with(['scores' => function ($query) {
                $query->select(['id','name']);
            }]
        )
        ->actives()
        ->paginate(14);
```